# Populate Combobox with the value of Another

Tags: vb.net

I'm having this little problem of Items collection cannot be modified when the datasource property is set and I don't know how to go about it. I am working in VB.NET

Here, I have populated names of Universities from my MSAccess DB in the University Combobox. On the SelectedChange Event of the University Combobox, the respective Faculties will be populated in another Combobox called Faculty Combo box. I am performing this operation using one Class definition and Querying from different methods outside the class.

So the error of "Items collection cannot be modified when the datasource property is set" is thrown when I try to select any University from the University Combobox. But I can't figure it out, everything seems OK while looking at it but I know something is wrong within the lines.

Here is my code:

Class Definition codes:

```
' Database connection
Public DBcon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                                            "Data Source=DATABASE.mdb")
'Get DB Command ready
Public DBCmd As OleDbCommand

'Database data
Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
Public DBDT As DataTable

'Parameter Query
Public Parameter As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

'Query Stats
Public Record As Integer
Public Exception As String

Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
    'Reseting the Query Stats
    Record = 0
    Exception = ""

    Try
        'Open a Connetion
        DBCon.Open()

        'Creating Database command
        DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

        'Loading Params into Database Command
        Parameter.ForEach(Sub(x) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(x))

        'Clear the List of Params
        Parameter.Clear()

        'Execute Command and Fill the DataTable
        DBDT = New DataTable
        DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
        Record = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    'Close Connection
    If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
```

Code for Populating the University Combo box:

```
    Try
        'Query string
        Dim myQuery As String
        myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Universities ORDER BY University_Name ASC"

        'Run query
        Access_DB.ExecQuery(myQuery)

        ' In case of Errors Report
        If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub

        'Fill the Combo box

        'Clear Combobox
        University_Choice.University_NameComboBox.Items.Clear()

        'Populate the combo box
        With University_Choice.University_NameComboBox
            .DisplayMember = "University_Name"
            .ValueMember = "University_ID"
            .DataSource = Access_DB.DBDT
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        End With

        'Display the first item found
        If Access_DB.Record > 0 Then University_Choice.University_NameComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0

    Catch ex As Exception
        Access_DB.Exception = ex.Message
    End Try
```

Code for Populating the Faculties Combo box:

```
   Try
        'Query string
        Dim QueryFaculty As String
        QueryFaculty = "SELECT * FROM University_Faculties " & _
            "WHERE University_ID = @UniversityID"

        Access_DB.ParamAdd("@UniversityID", "%" & _
                                 University_Choice.University_NameComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "%")

        'Run query
        Access_DB.ExecQuery(QueryFaculty)

        'In case of errors report
        If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub

        'Clear
        University_Choice.cboFaculty.Items.Clear()

        'Populate the combo box
        With University_Choice.cboFaculty
            .DisplayMember = "Faculty_Name"
            .ValueMember = "University_Faculties_ID"
            .DataSource = AccessDB.DBDT
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        End With

        'Display the first item found
        If Access_DB.Record > 0 Then University_Choice.cboFaculty.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        Access_DB.Exception = ex.Message
    End Try
```

Please if you need any further Info please let me know.

Comment: Ok... Where is your issue? Does the stack trace indicate a line of code that throws the error?

Comment: Just putting entire code instead of specific code snippets is not going to help. Users will not want to spend time first reading through chunk of the source code and providing solutions. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Put a break point at `If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub` and check if Access_DB returns rows along with University_Name and University_ID. This you check in watch window.

Comment: I have seen my problems, i was actually clearing my Faculty combobox each time the method is fired. Thanks so much you guys are really great!!!

Comment: But after removing that line causing the problem, the Faculty combobox still was not populated, i thought the Parameter.Clear() method is the problem. Next, when i got rid of the  Parameter.Clear() method i got an error saying "The OleDbParameter is already contained by another OleDbParameter collection". Then i used the Remove() method of the Parameter nothing still was still populated.

Answer (score 0):

`AccessDB` should be `Access_DB`.

```
With University_Choice.cboFaculty
    .DisplayMember = "Faculty_Name"
    .ValueMember = "University_Faculties_ID"
    .DataSource = Access_DB.DBDT   'Typo here
    .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
End With
```

Comment: Am very sorry for that long code just noticed it's a kind of vague.

Comment: When i checked through the lines, i found that the "Record" variable is always rested to 0 each time in the Class definition code i.e here     'Reseting the Query Stats
    Record = 0. But the Try...Catch block did not specify a particular line where the error is. All i discovered is when the method for populating the faculty is fired, it will still go through same class definition, thereby reset the "Record" variable to zero. Any idea is accepted please am new to this forum. Thanks